# Link click to page with getInitialProps doesn't unmount current component or show loading

Tags: next.js

I have a Page1 with link to page two:

```
const Page1 = () => {
  return <Link href='Page2'><a>Page2</a></Link>
}
```

When i click on Link, Page1 doesn't unmounts until Page2.getInitialProps fetch complete loading data and return it.

```
const Page2 = ({ init }) => {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(init)</div>
}

Page2.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const init = await fetch('smth')

  return { init }
}
```

Problem is for user it confusing that after hi pressed Link button, nothing happening for a second or two. For client side navigation i hope there is a way to show some Loading component after any link get pressed, or at least unmount current component. Almost all my pages have getInitialProps, so i hope about some generic way to do it, not manual.

My _app.js:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <ThemeContextProvider>
          <Header />
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          <Footer />
      </ThemeContextProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [this example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-loading).
Basically you can use [custom app](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) to override  and control the default page initialization and show your loading animation